# Get file path from excels cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need help how to get the file path from excel woorbook.
Path is save it in Cell C3 in excel sheet1.

And I want it  with my macro code to get that particular value from Cell C3 that I  have in excel and  set it to S1.

example:
Now my code work like this:
' Set s1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\25012023\master_NEW.xlsx")
But I don't wanna to fix that path name here in  the module.
I wanted to be more dynamically.

I save it that path in excel cell , but now I don't know how to get the value from there.
I tried with this?
Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value
But without any success.

Suggestions?

Comment: Dim MyFile As String

MyFile = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")
Set s1 = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)

Comment: Application.GetOpenFilename will open file selector and return path to a file upon selecting one. ThisWorkbook.Path will return a path to the workbook the code is run from. As far as your code is concerned, you only need "Set" when assigning objects. Range.Value is not an object so you can't use "Set".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this formula will produce a dynamic file path/name in Excel. Simply enter this formula into cell A1 (substitute that cell address for another of your choosing:

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1),1)-1)
```

I use this frequently when I need a dynamic way of getting the file name and path for Power Query for files that are on SharePoint.